# select and remove class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, selector, getelementsbyclassname

I have this code:

`<div class="d-none d-js-block">
...
</div>`

How can I remove the class attribute using javascript selector.
I'm using this code:

`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("d-none d-js-block");
 element.classList.remove("d-none d-js-block");`

I'm also using this code:

```
`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("d-d-none d-js-block");
element.removeAttr("class");`
```

This code is not working too;
How can I remove the class?

Comment: There is no `removeAttr` method on HTMLCollections. Also, your element has the class `d-none` but you're looking for `d-d-none`. See the link question's answers for more, but if you're using jQuery, `$(".d-none.d-jsblock").removeClass("d-none d-jsblock");`.

Comment: Removing the entire `class` attribute isn't usually your best bet, in case you want to have other, unrelated classes on the element later. (That's why I used `removeClass` above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the comma separated class names in the `remove()` function. And also make use of `querySelector()` if you have only that one element to select and remove the classes:

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".d-none.d-js-block");
element.classList.remove("d-none", "d-js-block");
```

```css
.d-none.d-js-block{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-none d-js-block">
 some HTML
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns a collection.So you need to pass the index of the element in that collection.

Alternatively you can use `querySelectorAll` and use `classList.remove`

Here usage of `setTimeout` is just to demonstrate the removal of the class.In your code you can avoid this

```js
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.d-js-block');
setTimeout(function() {
  element.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove("d-none");
    item.classList.remove("d-js-block");
  })

}, 3000)
```

```css
.d-none {
  color: green;
}

.d-js-block {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-none d-js-block">
  test</div>
```